# Images not going straight into array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small problem with some code here. I am trying to populate a collection view with  Five Names, descriptions and Images.

I am able to successfully to download all of the above into their respected arrays.

The problem is that the first time I perform the segue the image array has zero values in it. Then I go back a page and re-enter the page to find that all of the arrays have been populated successfully....

This is really annoying. Here is my code:

```
//arrays of names, descriptions and images
    var names:[String] = []
    var descriptions: [String] = []
    var imagesArray: [UIImage] = []
```

Heres where I get the images:

```
func downloadImages(){
        for x in 1...5{
            
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.imagesLocation.com/(x).png")
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){(data, response, error) in
                
                guard
                    let data = data,
                    let newImage = UIImage(data: data)
                    else{
                        print("Could not load image from URL: ",url!)
                        return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imagesArray.append(newImage)
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
        }
        
        loadDataFromFirebase()
    }
```

Heres where I download the Names and Descriptions from:

```
 func loadDataFromFirebase() {
        // Fetch and convert data
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection(self.shopName).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                    let description = document.get("Description") as! String
                    self.names.append(name)
                    self.descriptions.append(description)
                }
                self.setupImages() //safe to do this here as the firebase data is valid
            }
        }
    }
```

Heres where I setup the collection view with the Names, Description and Images array contents:

```
func setupImages(){
    
    do {
        if imagesArray.count < 5 || names.count < 5  || descriptions.count < 5 {
            throw MyError.FoundNil("Something hasnt loaded")
        }
        
        self.pages = [
            Page(imageName: imagesArray[0], headerText: names[0], bodyText: descriptions[0]),
            
            Page(imageName: imagesArray[1], headerText: names[1], bodyText: descriptions[1]),
            
            Page(imageName: imagesArray[2], headerText: names[2], bodyText: descriptions[2]),
            
            Page(imageName: imagesArray[3], headerText: names[3], bodyText: descriptions[3]),
            
            Page(imageName: imagesArray[4], headerText: names[4], bodyText: descriptions[4]),
        ]
    }
    catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

As you can see from the image below, every array is populating successfully apart from the images array:

[image]

Here is the segue from the previous page's code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNext", sender: self)   
        }
```

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: where are you calling this function ?

Comment: I call the 'downloadImages' function from the viewWillAppear

Comment: `print("Could not load image from URL: ",url!)` check for this line in debug

Comment: Please read about asynchronous execution first.

Comment: zero matches found. I think they are downloading successfully but not appending to the array quick enough

Comment: @koen yup, im positive

Comment: @mag_zbc Is this code badly wrong?

Comment: You just need to understand how multithreading works. In short, download will happen on some background thread, so by the time you call `loadDataFromFirebase`, your images will not have finished downloading yet.

Comment: @mag_zbc I am new to this and am a little lost with how to place the downloadImages function on the main thread

Comment: You don't. And the closure you pass to `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is just a completion handler, which will execute **after** download has finished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217552/discussion-between-mick1996-and-mag-zbc).

Comment: you can use dispatchGroup here

Comment: @jawadAli where?

Comment: Isn't your URL wrong? You have `https://www.imagesLocation.com/(x).png` but it should be `.com/\(x).png` –– you're missing the backslash for string interpolation.

Comment: @Daniel the images populate the array and load on the second time the page is opened. This shows that the url isnt the problem

Comment: I'm not claiming that is the only issue (it is not). I am only pointing out what seems to be a typo.

Comment: @Daniel thank you for pointing that out, it is a typo. Do you have any ideas for me to get the images array to populate the first time the page is opened

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if it helps or you have any questions.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! I will try and get back to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is just a variant of the classic, "Why is my asynchronous  function returning empty data?" I've answered a couple of these questions, and I'll include an analogy that explains the issue. You might understand the issue already, but I'll include it anyway for future readers:

> Your mom is cooking dinner and asks you to go buy a lemon.
>
> She starts cooking, but she has no lemon!
>
> Why? Because you haven't yet returned from the supermarket, and your
> mom didn't wait.

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57859919/5078779)</sup>

---

The main issue here is that you are calling `loadDataFromFirebase` way too early. You assume that it will execute only after your URL requests have completed, but that is not the case. Why? Because the URL requests are executed *asynchronously*. That is, they run on another thread instead of blocking the thread that calls `dataTask.resume`. This is why, as Shashank  Mishra suggests, you should use a `DispatchGroup`. Additionally, there is no guarantee that your images will load in the order that you begin the data tasks. I have included a fix below.

Generally, I would recommend defining variables strictly in the scopes in which you need them. Keeping `names`, `descriptions`, and `images` at such a high scope makes it too easy to make mistakes. I suggest refactoring your functions and deleting those three class-level arrays. Instead:

```
func loadDataFromFirebase(images: [UIImage]) {
    // same function as you posted, except make names and descriptions local variables and
    // replace self.setupImages() with:
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setupImages(images: images, names: names, descriptions: descriptions)
    }
}

func setupImages(images: [UIImage], names: [String], descriptions: [String]) {
    guard images.count == 5, names.count == 5, descriptions.count == 5 else {
        print("Missing data.")
        return
    }

    self.pages = (0..<5).map({ Page(image: images[$0], header: names[$0], body: descriptions[$0]) })
    // super important!!!
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Finally, here is my suggestion for a thread-safe `downloadImages` function:

```
func downloadImages() {
    var images = [UIImage?](repeating: nil, count: 5)
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    for i in 1...5 {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.imagesLocation.com/\(i).png")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                print("Could not load image from", url)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
                return
            }
            
            images[i] = image
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }.resume()
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        guard images.allSatisfy({$0 != nil}) else {
            print("Failed to fetch all images.")
            return
        }
        self.loadDataFromFirebase(images: images.compactMap({$0}))
    }
}
```

As Fattie pointed out, you should use `addSnapshotListener` rather than `getDocuments`. Also, you should add the listener/get documents while downloading the images instead of after, which will be faster. However, I am not adding either to my answer because this is already quite long, and if you have trouble with it you can post another question.

Comment: thank you Daniel! I will try this and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DispatchGroup to achieve asynchronous calls -

```
func downloadImages() {

   let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for x in 1...5 {
         
         dispatchGroup.enter()
        
         let url = URL(string: "https://www.imagesLocation.com/(x).png")
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){(data, response, error) in
             guard
                 let data = data,
                 let newImage = UIImage(data: data)
                 else{
                     print("Could not load image from URL: ",url!)
                     dispatchGroup.leave()
                     return
             }
             self.imagesArray.append(newImage)
             dispatchGroup.leave()
         }
         task.resume()
     }
     dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.loadDataFromFirebase()
     }
 }
```

Call "loadDataFromFirebase()" method on getting all 5 responses as above. It will always have all images before loading it on view.

Comment: thank you for your response! unfortunately this does not work :( the first time I segue to the page it does not work but when I unwind and go back to the same page the arrays populate correctly :(

Comment: You should perform segue to the page after "dispatchGroup.notify()", otherwise you will not get images in next page because images are getting downloaded asynchronously. Can you show me the segue code as well?

Comment: This answer is completely, totally wrong.  The OP is misunderstanding how Firebase works.

Comment: @Fattie downloadImages() is downloading the images asynchronously. loadDataFromFirebase() is getting called just after for loop(irrespective of the image download status) and loadDataFromFirebase() is using that image array. So DispatchQueue usage is correct.

Comment: @ShashankMishra , your understanding of Dispatch is correct.  But (1) before we get within a mile of that, the Firebase approach is completely wrong  :)  (2) You do not in any way use Dispatch when using Firebase.

Comment: I reload the collection view in the loadDataFromFirebase, but since the array isnt populating correctly I believe this is not the issue @ShashankMishra

Comment: @mick1996 If images are downloading correctly, then it can be only reloading issue on main thread. Can you try to reload collectionview after getting response from firebase in main thread. Try it once.

Comment: @ShashankMishra I added self.collectionView?.reloadData() before I leave the dispatchGroup and sadly this did not work. By any chance do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @ShashankMishra again I tried that again but it didnt work. I put a breakpoint on after calling that and the images array has 0 values in it whereas the other arrays are correctly populated! Thank you again for your help

Comment: @mick oh that means image is not getting appended in imagesArray. Can you please add breakpoints in download image method and there may be download  response error or invalid data because of guard statement was getting failed and images are not getting appended to array. I will simulate the same at my end and let you know in case of success.

Comment: @ShashankMishra I will try this and get back to you!

Answer (score -2):

You're misunderstanding how Firebase works.

Essentially.

1. Don't use `getDocuments`.  Use `.addSnapshotListener`

and

2. Basically each time the snapshot arrives, simply call `.reloadData()` on the table.

A full tutorial is beyond the scope of an answer here but there are many, many, tutorials around.

Just a typical fragment ...

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore().db.collection("yourCollection")
        .whereField("user", isEqualTo: uid)
        .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            guard let ds = documentSnapshot else {
                return print("error: \(error!)")
            }
            
            self.displayItems =  .. that data
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Note the `.reloadData()`

## Also ..

It's true that you *can* store an image (binary data) right in Firestore.

But really never, ever, do that - it's completely useless.

Simply use the dead-easy Firebase/Storage system where you can host images for free. Then they have completely normal URLs and so on.

Full tutorial:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626214/294884

Comment: Thank you for your response, Firebase isnt the issue here its the downloadImages function that only populates the array of images the second time the page is opened